# Read SQL Server Geometry datatype in R

Tags: r, sql-server, geometry, intersection

I have two datasets that come from ArcGis, stored in SQL Server. I have a column called - `Shape` which is a `geometry` data type and the value looks like this:

```
0x110F0000010407000000DCD781517FD76F4140FAED5B2EFF46C190C2F53C9FD76F41A0703D5242FF46C1C8BAB873A1D76F416888632504FF46C1B0BFECF4A3D76F41801D38F7C5FE46C19031770984D76F41A080264AB5FE46C114D0448881D76F4100B37B6AF2FE46C1DCD781517FD76F4140FAED5B2EFF46C101000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003
```

After executing this query for my Polygon dataset: `SELECT Shape.STGeometryType() AS GeometryType FROM dbo.POLY`

I get `Polygon`.

I have another dataset that is a `POINT` dataset which also has the same column `Shape`.

I use this query to do an Intersect between the two datasets:

```
update ABC 
    set ABC.ID = mb.ID
    from STG ABC 
    join POLY mb with (index([SPIDX_POLY_Shape]))
    on ABC.Shape.STIntersects(mb.Shape) = 1
```

My question is : How can I read this data into R, specially the `Shape` column, when I connect my SQL Server database. 
And my second question is which function will help me execute the above spatial intersect query? 
I am good with R, but bad with Spatial Analysis. I am not looking for you all to write me a code, but help me understand some concepts.

Answer (score 1):

There is functions `wkb::readWKB` and `rgeos::readWKT` that return `Spatial*DataFrame`s in R.

The general idea is to cast your geometry to one of these types and build the objects after reading the right type with SQL. You can connect to SQL Server with `RODBC`, or with this package: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RSQLServer/index.html

(I haven't used `RSQLServer`. )

Your database will have converter functions to cast data to a useable type. In Manifold GIS I use

```
CGeomWKB(Geom(ID))
```

inside the SQL query which returns a column of WKB type, then I read that with wkb::readWKB. SQL Server would have similar facilities.

You can see this in action in this function: https://github.com/mdsumner/manifoldr/blob/master/R/manifoldr.r

Note that R's Spatial Classes don't support mixing of types, like polygons, lines and points in the same data set so you'll need to filter out the ones you want to build individually if you see layers with this. Also note that WKB and WKT don't include the CRS, though Manifold's Geom does (in their format), and SQL Server may do similar. My Manifold code gets that CRS via a different mechanism.

Ultimately you could parse the native (or Shape) SQL Server Geom rather than casting to these other types, perhaps with `readBin` but that's another level of complexity.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the `rgeos` and `sp` package to create my SpatialPointDataFrame. But, I have run into another problem and that is my loop keeps running forever. I've got 2 million pts nd its been sitting for 3.5 hours on it. My R statements:
`point.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT[1]),data=data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID[1], LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO[1]))
for (n in 2:as.integer(cnt)) {
  point.sp <- rbind(point.sp, 
                    SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT[n]), 
                                           data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID[n], LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO[n])))
}`

Comment: readWKT is vectorized, there's no need to loop - and especially not by "growing" the object incrementally - that is hopelessly inefficient. If you have another question, don't post it in comments, but probably all you need is to remove the index: `SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT),data=data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID, LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO))` - might need to handle the rownames too.

Comment: I've posted a new question. Thank you and sorry my bad. [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182497/spatialpointsdataframe-too-slow-for-loop]

Comment: Cripes, sorry - readWKT is *not* vectorized. I don't know why that is. I'll see if can be. There'll be a much faster way to do it, and via WKB would be much better.