# SpatialPointsDataFrame too slow FOR LOOP

Tags: r, sql-server, sp

I've run into a small problem where my `for` loop has been running for 3.5 hrs+. I have a Geodataset in `SQL Server` with a field called `Shape` that stores co-ordinates in `geometry` data type. Firstly, I connect R to my DB via `ODBC`  and retrieve the information I want (also converting the `Shape` column to something readable)

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(RODBC)
ch<-odbcConnect("SpatialAnalysis", rows_at_time=1)
df<-sqlQuery(ch, "select OBJECTID, LOT_NO, Shape.STAsText() as WKT FROM SRC_PLI_QLD")
cnt<-sqlQuery(ch, "select count(OBJECTID) from SRC_PLI_QLD")
```

This has 2.5 million points. I now read them into a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, reading the first element first.

```
point.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT[1]),
                                   data=data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID[1], LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO[1]))
```

Now I read the rest of the elements. **AND this is where the problem is**. It has been 3.5 hrs and still running.

```
for (n in 2:as.integer(cnt)) {
  point.sp <- rbind(point.sp, 
                    SpatialPointsDataFrame(readWKT(df$WKT[n]), 
                                           data.frame(OBJECTID=df$OBJECTID[n], LOT_NO=df$LOT_NO[n])))
}
```

What is the problem in the above mentioned `for` loop? Is there another way I can do this?

Comment: Given that these are just points, why are you using a Geometry type? Why not just get X/Y or long/lat from the query?

Comment: In my SQL, there is a `Shape` column that has values like this :`x110F0000010407000000DCD781517FD76F4140FAED5B2EFF46C190C2F53C9FD76F41A0703D5242FF46C1C8BAB873A1D76F416888632504FF46C1B0BFECF4A3D76F41801D38F7C5FE46C19031770984D76F41A080264AB5FE46C114D0448881D76F4100B37B6AF2FE46C1DCD781517FD76F4140FAED5B2EFF46C101000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003`. These are my co-ordinates. I am extracting them out using `Shape.AsText()`. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think we need to explore the SQL Server doc. What version etc. Probably another question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this in another way and it took less than 10 seconds.  The change was in the query. Instead of retrieving `Shape.STAsText()` as a WKT object from `Shape` column, I retrieved the `Lat` and `Long` value from `Shape`

```
df<-sqlQuery(ch, "select OBJECTID, LOT_NO, Shape.STY as Lat, Shape.STX as Lon FROM SRC_PLI_QLD")
cnt<-sqlQuery(ch, "select count(OBJECTID) from SRC_PLI_QLD")
```

Then I did :

```
coordinates(df) =~Lat+Lon
```

and my dataframe `df` has been converted to a SpatialPointsDataFrame

```
> class(df)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)
xy <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df$WKT,  function(x) coordinates(readWKT(x))))
```

Note: it turns out you can vectorize readWKT by pasting all the wkt text strings together, the underlying code splits them. Not really sure why this is the case, it's inconvenient.

But it's kind of pointless given that every object is just a single coordinate pair. You could use a similar approach for polygons and lines, but it's slightly different. `SpatialPoints` don't really have the same structure as the other classes, though `SpatialMultipoints` do . . .

Then you need to reconstruct the Spatial stuff:

```
point.sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(SpatialPoints(xy), data = df, match.ID = TRUE)
```

Just set `match.ID` to FALSE if it gives you grief. `SpatialPoints` has a `proj4string` argument where you can pass in the `CRS(proj.4)`.

For points (but not multipoints) I would just use the db query to get x/y, then use `coordinates(df) <- c("x", "y")`.

Comment: Thanks. My main goal is to do this with a Polygon dataset and then do an intersect between the Points and Polygon dataset to retrieve more attributes. I am doing all this correctly?

Comment: BTW the rbind, do.call method takes equally the same time, as lapply is based on a for-loop.

Comment: Looks like you are right, did not expect that. Use WKB and wkb::readWKB instead. Text is inefficient.

Comment: Another option is to use readOGR() with the MSSQLSpatial driver.

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help. I solved it another way, answer below